# Launching a file from a PC using Bluetooth from a phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to find a way to launch a Powerpoint file in a PC (the files are shared through the cloud, eg. through Google Drive) from an Android phone by using a Bluetooth link. The phone should then be able to control the presentation (like Office Remote/ Asus Remote Link).

This will be very useful in conferences where there are many speakers and different powerpoint files to be broadcasted.

Comment: Nothing about this is a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a huge Coding. There should be desktop application for PC and android application for cellphone by which we can connect both via wireless connection or Bluetooth. Try to break your question and find them one by one or ask them one by one then you can achieve your task.